# Ignore timestamps in org-agenda my manually adding a tag to the timestamp?

Tags: org-mode

Is there a way to ignore specific timestamps in org-agenda view?

In my specific case, say I have two files `file1.org` and `file2.org` which both are org agenda files, but contain the same timestamp. Lets say for example, both contain a timestamp for the beginning of the summer holidays.

So is there a way to add manually something like a tag to the timestamp in `file2.org` such that this timestamp is ignored in the org-agenda view?

Comment: Not that I know of, but you can use an agenda view with  a skip function to just skip the entry. To find out more, say `C-h i g (org) special agenda views`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of tagging, you could turn one of them into an inactive timestamp, which prevents from showing up in the agenda.
With point on the timestamp:

```
C-c !
```

You can also toggle with point on the delimiter of the timestamp ( `< or [` ) and press `<S-up>` or `<S-down>`